# Cannot initialize TinyMCE on target node: loading stylesheet crashes

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to initialize TinyMCE on an existing DOM element like this:

```
    tinymce.init({
        target: editorNode,
        menubar: true,
        inline: true
   });
```

This fails, with the following error in the console:

```
tinymce.js:3193 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at tinymce.js:3193
    at wait (tinymce.js:3182)
    at HTMLLinkElement.waitForWebKitLinkLoaded (tinymce.js:3191)
```

When I debug this, it looks like TinyMCE is trying to load style sheets (which is fine), but it is using the target element as `documentOrShadowRoot` to call

```
    var styleSheets = documentOrShadowRoot.styleSheets;
    var i = styleSheets.length;
```

This obviously fails, because that's not where the stylesheets are kept.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same error, when I was adding editor in new modal window.
Try to attach editorNode to the DOM first, then invoke tinymce, or just delay tinymce initialization, e.g:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    tinymce.init({
        (...)
        target : editorNode
    })
}, 10);
```

This solved issue in my case. :)